# p:chart legendPosition

Tags: jsf, primefaces, charts

I'm having a problem with legend in line chart. For only two series there used to occurs multiple legends.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL2fb.png)

I've used following code in the managed bean

```
transactionModel=initLinearModel();
       transactionModel.setTitle("Daily Transaction Graph for Fiscal Year"+selectedYar);
       transactionModel.setLegendPosition("ne");
       transactionModel.setZoom(true);
       transactionModel.setAnimate(true);    
       transactionModel.setSeriesColors("00ffff,000aaa");
       transactionModel.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, new CategoryAxis(selectedType));
       Axis yAxis=transactionModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
       yAxis.setLabel("Transaction");
```

Comment: source code formating

Answer (score -1):

I made mistake inserting addSeries() in loop as:

allTransaction = loginBeanLocal.getData(selectedYar);
transactionModel = initLinearModel();
        transactionModel.setTitle("Daily Transaction Graph for Fiscal Year" + selectedYar);
        transactionModel.setLegendPosition("ne");
        transactionModel.setZoom(true);
        transactionModel.setAnimate(true);

```
    transactionModel.setSeriesColors("00ffff,000aaa");
    transactionModel.setMouseoverHighlight(true);
    transactionModel.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, new CategoryAxis(selectedType));
    Axis yAxis = transactionModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    yAxis.setLabel("Transaction");

for (Object[] obj : allTransaction) {


            series1.set(obj[0], (BigInteger) obj[1]);
            series2.set(obj[0], ((Double) obj[3]) / 1000);

           model.addSeries(series1);
          model.addSeries(series2);

        }
```

addseries should be kept outside of the loop.

Comment: So you actualltly post code in an answer that is **not good**? And an answer that has no visible correlation to the question? Please improve both!